# wikipedia api results vary between list and generator queries

Tags: mediawiki, wiki, wikipedia-api, mediawiki-api

I'm exploring wiki apis...

Based on the below post, i 've some doubts.
[Wikipedia list=search REST API: how to retrieve also Url of matching articles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8930867/wikipedia-list-search-rest-api-how-to-retrieve-also-url-of-matching-articles/13492215#13492215)

I need to fetch the wiki URLs for my search. So I used `generator=search` instead of `list=search`

But the results got from both methods vary in the order they are returned.

Can someone tell me based on what factor the results are being ordered in generator method?

sample try:

- generator: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&generator=search&gsrsearch=sachin+tendulkar&format=jsonfm&prop=info&inprop=url|displaytitle
- list: http://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php?action=query&list=search&srsearch=sachin+tendulkar&format=jsonfm

Comment: Good question. The entries of one generator page seem to be sorted alphabetically by title.

Comment: Why does that matter to you? The `search` module doesn't have `sort` parameter, so I think that means the order is undefined.

Comment: The search results always have a score. In a `list`, it is arranged by its score, but in a `generator`, it is sorted by `pageid`. Although, you won't lose the search ranking, it is given by the `index`.

Comment: @Bergi Nope, it is actually sorted by `pageid`, and not `title`.